# Read a property from a maven POM in a bash script (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, maven

I am using maven as my build tool. Below is a snippet from my POM.

```
    <properties>
        <geb.version>2.2</geb.version>
        <selenium.version>3.14.0</selenium.version>
        <groovy.version>2.4.14</groovy.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4</spock.version>
        <surefire.plugin.version>2.20</surefire.plugin.version>
        <surefire.plugin.parallel>methods</surefire.plugin.parallel>
        <selenium.host>XXXXX</selenium.host>
    </properties>
```

I am writing an linux executable and I want to access `<selenium.host>` property in my bash script. How do I do this?

```
DEFAULT_ADDRESS=$(get address from POM here)
```

Please note that my script and POM file are in the same directory.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best and reliable solution would be to use [maven-help-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) like this:

```
ADDRESS=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=selenium.host -q -DforceStdout)
```

If you don't have specified the version of maven-help-plugin in your pom file you should use the following:

```
ADDRESS=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=selenium.host -q -DforceStdout)
```

The result is that the given property is read from pom file and then the value is assigned to `ADDRESS`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that:

```
DEFAULT_ADDRESS=`cat pom.xml | grep "selenium.host" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1`
```

Comment: Works like a charm for me: cat ./pom.xml | grep "java.version" | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1

Answer (score 2):

You can use xmllint to parse xml from the command line:

```
address=$(xmllint --xpath "string(//properties/selenium.host)" file.xml)
echo "$address"
```

Or if xmllint is not available, and tag `<selenium.host>` only appears once:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<selenium.host>).*(?=</selenium.host>)' file.xml
```

Comment: Anyone who doesn't have access to -P flag on mac OSX. You can use `brew install grep` command. This will install ggrep command which allows the -P flag to work in mac OSX. And you can also use `-m 1` to parse the first output.